# On-Screen Buttons for android apps?

Tags: android

How do I create on-screen buttons for android apps. I am using the SDK's Lunar Lander game as a base, and I want to make it so that you don't need a keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

To create a button you add something like this in your layout XML file:

```
<Button             
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Button 1"/>
```

To get a hook to the button in your code where you can add some action when the button is pressed add an OnClickListener:

```
findViewById(R.id.button_1).setOnClickListener(new MyButtonListener());
```

Declare the OnClickListener as a private class (or inline)

```
private class MyButtonListener implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Your code doing something cool goes here...
        System.out.println("Click!");
    }
}
```

Please look in the documentation that Mr Dittmar posted links to for more details, but this should hopefully get you started. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation on how to [create a layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html). After that, the documentation on how to [create and handle buttons](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) might come handy.